# k8s container CPU usage reached limit cause memory to also be throttled?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm not sure if this is the correct behavior of k8s, so I'm asking it here

This is my helm value for CPU and memory:

```
resources:
      limits:
        cpu: 4000m
        memory: 8Gi
      requests:
        cpu: 2000m
        memory: 4Gi
```

I checked the datadog metrics, and the container CPU usage is nearly 4s (not sure if this is related to the 4000m CPU limit) around the time the issue happened (both CPU and memory usage are reduced at that time) and it causes the loss of some data that is stored inside the memory (we are using https://github.com/orcaman/concurrent-map as a kind of in-mem cache)

The memory usage of the container is only around 3Gi before the incident happened, so it does not reach the memory limit.

Is there any documentation of k8s mentioning that behavior? And how I can fix it?
Thanks.

---

UPDATE:

I checked `kubectl top pods` and I got this result.
Pods that nearly reach the CPU limit are the pods that have a problem

[image]

Looks like there is a connection here

Comment: Did you pod restart? If there was not enough memory available, your pod would have been killed. Of your pod has not been killed and you still have data loss, that sounds more like an applicative issue.

Comment: @GaëlJ no, it does not restart. I checked k8s doc and OOM causes pod to restart is only applied to "memory", not "CPU".
I'm asking about the CPU limit. The memory usage of the container is only around 3Gi before the incident happened, so it does not reach the memory limit.

Comment: try to set `limits.memory` as same as `requests.memory` to prevent overcommit memory.
probably just run out of physical memory cause data lose and high cpu usage.

Comment: Hi @0xh8h have you check this [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#resource-requests-and-limits-of-pod-and-container)?

Comment: I didn't get what's the issue then? If CPU got throttled, this does not affect your data in memory. How does it relate to your data loss? It's an applicative issue of it happens.